# How can I find a line through 3D points?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, linear-regression, best-fit-curve

This is easier explained with pictures. I have these green points:

[image: Points (no line)]

And I want to get a few points along this red line:

[image: Points (with line)]

This is a top view, but I have complete XYZ coordinates for each point. I also have which vertex is connected to which other vertex.

It almost seems like you could just take the midpoint of each of those green edges and draw a line through them but you can see how that wouldn't really work near the end.

**Is there an algorithm I can use to find a line of best fit through these 3D points?**

I'm using Three.js if that makes a difference.

Comment: Some leads here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500149/find-lines-in-a-cloud-of-points

Answer (score 1):

This task is equal to noise suppression. 
the simplest algorithm (end of array will not be filtered):

```
double array[];
int count, depth;
// 1 < depth < count

for (int i = 0; i < count - depth; i++)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < depth; j++)
    {
        sum += array[i + j];
    }
    array[i] = sum / depth;
}
```

You can find more info googling Median Filter and Noise Suppression